# Load only a portion of a view in CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

If i have a view named segments.php in view folder of codeigniter and it is structured with divs, for example:

```
<div id="a">
Content for a goes here ...
</div>
<div id="b">
Content for b goes here ...
</div>
```

and that i want to load only a section of it, that is, retrieve each div alone as it is done using jQuery .load function as: $(selector).load("segments.php #a");

How can i load a section of this view in CodeIgniter?

Hope am clear with my question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Will need some conditional logic based on data passed to view such as `if(), switch(), while()` etc

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  
Maybe you should split your view in partial views and load them appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. CodeIgniter needs to solve this problem or provide a way of overriding load method with that of jQuery. Thank you for saving my time

Comment: So what are the conditions that determine whether to send full view or not? Question is too vague to provide much of an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter doesn't have any built in method of only loading part of a view. As mentioned in the comments, you either have to use logic inside the view to show/hide what you want or split the file into multiple views and load the ones you need.

With PHP logic:

`$(selector).load("segments.php?id=a")`;

```
<? switch($this->input->get('id')):
   case 'a': ?>
    <div id="a">
        Content for a goes here ...
    </div>
<? break;
   case 'b': ?>
    <div id="b">
        Content for b goes here ...
    </div>
<? endswitch; ?>
```